# Does Bitlocker securely erase the blocks where the first and last partition will go?

Tags: windows, bitlocker, forensics

I have a question regarding bitlocker. Suppose I have any operating system installed on an unencrypted disk (windows for example) and I have confidential data on it. Then, someone formats the disk and installs windows, but this time encrypts the disk with bitlocker. Then, bitlocker only encrypts the c partition, but leaves the EFI and recovery partition unencrypted. So my question is: Is it possible to recover some confidential data from the original windows by searching the EFI and recovery partition, since as I said they are not encrypted by bitlocker, and they are not completely overwritten as seen in the image (100% available).

[image]

Comment: The _100% available_ isn’t related to BitLocker in any way. This value is also incorrectly displayed for unmounted partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of.

I doubt an adversary will get anything confidential from scanning the unencrypted "standard"partitions.

What is more likely concerns are -

- If " Used space only" encryptio  is selected Bitlocker does not overwrite the whole partition initially, it will likely be possible to recover some old data that was there before the disk was encrypted- you cpuld likely get data with tools as simple as Recuva or Photorec.
- If the disk has bad sectors or is an SSD (with overprovisioning - which is standard), fragments of old data will not be encrypted.  Getting to these is much harder then the abive scenario, and the amount if data that can be recovered is way smaller, but it is possible for an expert to get some data off the drive.

Best practice is to ensure full disk encryption/bitlocker is enabled before any sensitive data is written - altjough that likely dies not help here.  Some SSD's have buil in full SSD encryption - if your disk happens to gave this, you can use secure erase to wipe the disk (secure erase is akin to automatic bit locker built into the drive - throw away the key and the data is scrambled).  Failing tjis the best you can do is fill up the encrypted disk and erase a few times to refuce - but by no means eliminate - data hidden in overprovisioned/bad blocks.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it was useful, so if the space used by the EFI partition and the windows recovery partition, are not overwritten 100%, then I could get data from any previous operating system that has not been encrypted?

Comment: (At least when it comes to SSD's) - Not quite.   The SSD itself does not know anything of partitions - these are a construct of the OS's, so not where the problem is.  Simplifying a wee bit - SSD's pretend to be fast hard drives - and the computer sees and communicates with them as if they have the same layout as hard drives, but within the SSD itself the data is represented very differently.   Because of the nature of SSD's, they wear out over time as they are written.  To make much less of an issue, SSD if you buy say a 1tb drive, the manufacturer might actually provide a 1.1tb of space....

Comment: The 0.1 tb being entirely invisible to the PC.   The SSD moves (and keeps track of) information on the drive, and spreads the load throughout the drive, including the overprovisioned bits to increase the drives lifespan.   This means that even if you overwrite the whole drive in the OS you still don't wipe the hidden 10%.   There are also cells which go bad over time, but which will still have some accessible data in them.    This requires special know-how and access beyond what most publicly available software recovery provides, but experts can get to it.

Answer (score 1):

Bitlocker has 2 options.

1. Encrypt the whole drive
2. Encrypt the part that has data on it.

Unless you have the encryption password you won't be able to decrypt anything that is encrypted.

The EFI and recovery partition, have none of your data they are exclusive to windows.

So if they choose to only encrypt part of the data, they could scrape the unencrypted part for data.

Use dban to wipe the whole drive.

Comment: Even dban won't fully erase an SSD - from the horses mouth - https://dban.org/blancco-drive-eraser/ - "Please note that DBAN does not erase SSDs or produce an audit-ready certificate of erasure"